# Column Headers Offset From Data in Wpf Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Good morning

I have a Wpf datagrid that is displaying an observable collection of a custom type

I group the data using a collection view source in XAML on two seperate properties, and I have styled the groups to display as expanders.

For clarity, as there is a lot of data I feel I have to use margins and spacing otherwise things look very cluttered.

My problem is that with two levels of hierarchical expanders the column data is now substantially offset from the column headers meaning that they do not properly line up.

I have tried several thing, like setting the margin of the column headers and the width (both actual and normal). However all of my attempts end up resizing the whole column so that the offset stays the same but the columns move.

so my question:

**How can I change the visible width or offset of a column header to ensure that the headers line up with the data**

- Visual Studio 2012
- Wpf
- C#
- DataGrid

**EDIT This is what I mean**

[image: Offset Columns]

**EDIT 2 - MY Xaml for Grouping**

```
<!--  Style for groups at top level.  -->
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander Margin="5,10,5,5"
                                  BorderBrush="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"
                                  BorderThickness="1"
                                  Header="{Binding Name}"
                                  IsExpanded="True">

                            <Expander.Template>
                                <!--  The basic expander  -->
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                                    <!--  Put a border around the expander  -->
                                    <Border Background="{Binding Path=Name,
                                                                 Converter={StaticResource ColourConverter}}"
                                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource GreyBrush}"
                                            BorderThickness="2"
                                            CornerRadius="3">

                                        <!--  Use a dock panel so that the toggle button is docked to the top and the content is docked to the bottom  -->
                                        <DockPanel Margin="0">

                                            <!--  Add the toggle button  -->
                                            <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton"
                                                          Margin="0"
                                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                                          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                                          FontSize="14"
                                                          FontWeight="Bold"
                                                          Foreground="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"
                                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                                                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                          OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                                                          Template="{StaticResource AnimatedExpanderButton}" />

                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpanderContent"
                                                              Margin="5"
                                                              ContentSource="Content"
                                                              DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                                              Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ExpanderButton,
                                                                                   Path=IsChecked,
                                                                                   Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Expander.Template>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
</GroupStyle>

<!--  Style for groups under the top level.  -->
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">

            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander Margin="5"
                                  Background="{Binding Path=Name,
                                                       Converter={StaticResource ColourConverter}}"
                                  IsExpanded="True"
                                  Visibility="{Binding Items[0].IsSelectedInSidebar,
                                                       Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">

                            <Expander.Template>
                                <!--  The basic expander  -->
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                                    <!--  Put a border around the expander  -->
                                    <Border Background="{Binding Path=Name,
                                                                 Converter={StaticResource ColourConverter}}"
                                            BorderBrush="{StaticResource GreyBrush}"
                                            BorderThickness="2"
                                            CornerRadius="3">

                                        <!--  Use a dock panel so that the toggle button is docked to the top and the content is docked to the bottom  -->
                                        <DockPanel Margin="0">

                                            <!--  Add the toggle button  -->
                                            <ToggleButton x:Name="ExpanderButton"
                                                          Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                                          DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                                          FontSize="12"
                                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                                                                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                          OverridesDefaultStyle="True"
                                                          Template="{StaticResource AnimatedExpanderButton}" />

                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpanderContent"
                                                              Margin="5"
                                                              ContentSource="Content"
                                                              DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                                                              Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ExpanderButton,
                                                                                   Path=IsChecked,
                                                                                   Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                                        </DockPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Expander.Template>
                            <Expander.Content>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource BlackBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="0" Margin="0" />

                                        <Border Grid.Row="1"
                                                Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource BlackBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                                                Visibility="{Binding Data.SettingRepository.MainDataSummaryVisible,
                                                                     Source={StaticResource BindingProxy},
                                                                     Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
                                            <Grid Background="{StaticResource WhiteBrush}">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                                               Margin="5"
                                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].Option1Title}"
                                                               Visibility="{Binding Data.SettingRepository.MainDataShowSampleOptions,
                                                                                    Source={StaticResource BindingProxy},
                                                                                    Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                                               Margin="5"
                                                               Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].Option1Data,
                                                                              Mode=OneWay}"
                                                               Visibility="{Binding Data.SettingRepository.MainDataShowSampleOptions,
                                                                                    Source={StaticResource BindingProxy},
                                                                                    Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />

                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                                                               Margin="5"
                                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].Option2Title}"
                                                               Visibility="{Binding Data.SettingRepository.MainDataShowSampleOptions,
                                                                                    Source={StaticResource BindingProxy},
                                                                                    Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3"
                                                               Margin="5"
                                                               Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].Option2Data,
                                                                              Mode=OneWay}"
                                                               Visibility="{Binding Data.SettingRepository.MainDataShowSampleOptions,
                                                                                    Source={StaticResource BindingProxy},
                                                                                    Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="4"
                                                               Margin="5"
                                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].Option3Title}"
                                                               Visibility="{Binding Data.SettingRepository.MainDataShowSampleOptions,
                                                                                    Source={StaticResource BindingProxy},
                                                                                    Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5"
                                                               Margin="5"
                                                               Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].Option3Data,
                                                                              Mode=OneWay}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="6"
                                                               Margin="5"
                                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].Option4Title}"
                                                               Visibility="{Binding Data.SettingRepository.MainDataShowSampleOptions,
                                                                                    Source={StaticResource BindingProxy},
                                                                                    Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="7"
                                                               Margin="5"
                                                               Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].Option4Data,
                                                                              Mode=OneWay}"
                                                               Visibility="{Binding Data.SettingRepository.MainDataShowSampleOptions,
                                                                                    Source={StaticResource BindingProxy},
                                                                                    Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}" />

                                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="8"
                                                               Margin="5"
                                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               Text="{x:Static languages:Strings.SampleIsAnnealedColumnHeader}" />
                                                    <CheckBox Grid.Column="9"
                                                              Margin="3,5,5,5"
                                                              IsChecked="{Binding Path=Items[0].SampleIsAnnealed,
                                                                                  Mode=OneWay}"
                                                              IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                                              Style="{StaticResource FandFCheckBox}" />
                                                </Grid>

                                                <!--  The mean Match temperature  -->
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                                           Text="{x:Static languages:Strings.MeanSampleMatchTemperatureTitle}" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].SampleMeanMatchTemperature,
                                                                          Mode=OneWay,
                                                                          StringFormat=\{0:N2\}}" />

                                                <!--  The match temperature range  -->
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                                           Text="{x:Static languages:Strings.SampleTemperatureRangeTitle}" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                                           Grid.Column="3"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].SampleMatchTemperatureRange}" />

                                                <!--  The match temperature standard deviation  -->
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                                           Grid.Column="4"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                                           Text="{x:Static languages:Strings.SampleTemperatureStandardDeviationTitle}" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                                                           Grid.Column="5"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].SampleMatchTemperatureStandardDeviation,
                                                                          Mode=OneWay,
                                                                          StringFormat=\{0:N3\}}" />

                                                <!--  The mean refractive index  -->
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                                           Text="{x:Static languages:Strings.SampleMeanRefractiveIndexTitle}" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                                                           Grid.Column="1"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].SampleMeanRefractiveIndex,
                                                                          Mode=OneWay,
                                                                          StringFormat=\{0:N5\}}" />

                                                <!--  The refractive index range  -->
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                                                           Grid.Column="2"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                                           Text="{x:Static languages:Strings.SampleRIRangeTitle}" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                                                           Grid.Column="3"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].SampleRefractiveIndexRange}" />

                                                <!--  The refractive index standard deviation  -->
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                                                           Grid.Column="4"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           FontWeight="Bold"
                                                           Text="{x:Static languages:Strings.SampleRIStandardDeviationTitle}" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"
                                                           Grid.Column="5"
                                                           Margin="5"
                                                           Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].SampleRefractiveIndexStandardDeviation,
                                                                          Mode=OneWay,
                                                                          StringFormat=\{0:N7\}}" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Expander.Content>
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
</GroupStyle>
```

Comment: Could you add some visuals: what you get and what you expect? This might help understand your problem.

Comment: I have uploaded a picture that I hope makes things clearer

Comment: Problem is in your template for grouping. Could you also add the xaml of the styling?

Comment: I have uploaded the group styles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `ColumnHeaderStyle` and there set a `RenderTransform` that moves the headers to the right.

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                //change the X value accordingly
                <TranslateTransform X="100"></TranslateTransform>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

**EDIT 2:**

As you mentioned, doing this will result in a small gap. To remove it you should set the left margin of the first column to a negative value, which stretches the header of this column to the left. You can do it like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        //change the margin accordingly
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-100 0 0 0" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                //change the X value accordingly
                <TranslateTransform X="100"></TranslateTransform>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
```

You have to set the `RenderTransform` here again, because this style overwrites the general `ColumnHeaderStyle`. To remove duplication you can add the render transfrom as a resource.

**EDIT:**

I just saw that you have a few margins on your `Expanders` and `ContentPresenters`. If you change them so that you have 0 margin to the left, it would align the content more to the left and reduce the alignment difference.

You would then need less offset on the `RenderTransform`.

Some examples of your code to illustrate what I mean:

```
<Expander Margin="5,10,5,5"
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpanderContent" Margin="5"
```

If you change it to

```
<Expander Margin="0,10,5,5"
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpanderContent" Margin="0 5 5 5"
```

the columns move more to the left.

Comment: Ok this is nearly what I want. however pushing the columns to the right has created an empty space to the left of the first column through which the data grid background now shows. Is there anyway that I could "Stretch the first column to fill this space?

Comment: @StevenWood see Edit 2, this should help you

Comment: I need the margins really as otherwise there is a lot of data that begins to look very cluttered and difficult to read. is there anything else I can do? I will mark your answer as accepted anyway but for a bonus point...

Comment: Maybe you could alternate the background (every second row/group has a lighter background color)